# How to Change the start time and end time of a LocalDate in JavaFX DateTime API

Tags: java, datetime, javafx, javafx-8, jodatime

I have developed a JavaFX application which uses `LocalDate()` in `Joda Time API`. The default start and end time of a day is `00:00:00 - 23:59:59`. I want to change this to `08:00:00 - 07:59:59 (Following Day)`.

The code which I used in my application to calculate yesterday's timeline is as follows:

```
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
LocalDate yesterday = now.minusDays(1);
```

This code calculates between `2015-10-25 00:00:00` and `2015-10-25 23:59:59`, but I want it to be between `2015-10-25 08:00:00` and `2015-10-26 07:59:59`.

I tried this using SQL and it works fine.

```
IF((NOW() > TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '00:00:00'))) AND (NOW() < TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '08:00:00'))),
(`created_date` >= TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(CURDATE() - 1), ' ', '08:00:00')) AND `created_date` < TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(CURDATE()), ' ', '08:00:00'))),
(`created_date` >= TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '08:00:00')) AND `created_date` < TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(CURDATE() + 1), ' ', '08:00:00'))))
```

The query is how do I achieve this with `JodaTime API`?.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the following logic:

- Get the current date time.
- If we're after 8, then the start date is today at 8
- Otherwise (it means we're between midnight and 8), the start date is yesterday at 8
- The end date is simply one day after the start date, minus 1 second.

Code:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime todayAt8 = now.withTime(8, 0, 0, 0);

LocalDateTime startDate = todayAt8.isBefore(now) ? todayAt8 : todayAt8.minusDays(1);
LocalDateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so how to calculate this with yesterday, day before yesterday and specified date range?

Comment: @Hiran With this code, `startDate` and `endDate` will correctly represent 08:00:00 - 07:59:59 (Following Day). I'm not sure I understand your remark.

Comment: above code is retrieving this result 

`2015-10-26 08:19:13
2015-10-27 08:19:12`

Comment: @Hiran See my edit, I forgot to set the minutes and seconds to 0.